# How to hide a div when I click any item on select option?

Tags: javascript

Is there other way to hide a div when I click any item on the select option? Im trying to hide this:

```
<div id="video-borderr" class="video-borderr">ljlkj<iframe src="<?php echo $row['links'];?>" allowfullscreen="true" class="videorow"></iframe><div class="video-text"> <?php echo $row['titles'];?><br><?php echo $row['dates'];?> </div></div>
```

using the code below but it is not working. I also tried other code I saw but nothing works.

```
<select id="state" multiple name="state" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); } hidehehehe(this);">

 <script>
    function hidehehehe() {
        document.getElementById("video-borderr").style.display = 'none';
    }
 </script>
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the responses, I think the onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); which I use to automatically submit the select option is the problem. I tried removing it and my hidehehehe works. Don't know why it happens. Is there any approach I can use?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the old code. I already edit my post, still not working.

Comment: I think the only possibility is that the div with id `video-borderr` is not in the DOM when you are changing the select value. Otherwise your code looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are getting errors in the console `Cannot read property 'submit' of null`

```
onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); } hidehehehe(this);"
                                          ^^^^^
```

Because here `this` is a reference of `select` and does not contain `form.submit`. As that is getting errored `hidehehehe` is never called.

**Solution**
You can solve it like this

```js
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
const videoBorder = document.getElementById("video-borderr");

function onSelectChange(mySelect) {
  if (mySelect.value != 0) {
    form.submit();
  }
  videoBorder.style.display = 'none';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // If above code doesn't work then you should wrap all the code here,
    // Since DOM is loaded and ready here.
});
```

```html
<div id="video-borderr">This is a video border div</div>

<form id="myForm">
  <select id="state" multiple name="state" onchange="onSelectChange(this)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess he needs to submit the form only when the selected value !=0 and otherwise hide the select element.

Comment: I use the onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }  to automatically submit the select option once its click. But that also affects my hidehehehe, whenever I remove that code, hidehehehe works. Do you know why that happens? Thank you!

Comment: @Pathfinder I have updated my answer, and I also recommend you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @Pathfinder Updated solution with a runnable code snippet.

Comment: I tested your code on a new html without changing anything but still doesn't work on my computer. But thanks for your help and effort!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create options for you select, I can't see any option above in your code! because the event is change so you need to have what you will change

```
document.getElementById("state").addEventListener("change",()=>{
    document.getElementById("video-borderr").style.display = "none";
})
```

```
 <div id="video-borderr">
     <h1>heading</h1>
 </div>
 <select id="state">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I do have  option on my code. Both my code above and your code for hiding a video-borderrr works but the problem is whenever onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }  is added, the code just doesn't work anymore. Do you know why that happens? Thank you!